# How to reduce network request count in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

Recently, I decided to migrate my hobby project to SvelteKit. During the migration process, I have tried building the project and run `npm run preview` to test the performance and I have noticed that SvelteKit increase the network request when importing class or component instead of inline some of those resources.

Here is what I have done. I have created a class as following:

```
/// Url.js

class Url {
    static HOME = "/";
    static BLOG = "/blog";
    static ABOUT = "/about";
}
```

```
/// Config.js

export const someConfig1 = "";
export const someConfig2 = "";
export const someConfig3 = "";
```

```
/// SomeComponent.svelte

<div>
    ... some code
    </slot>
</div>
```

And then I just import **Url.js**, **Config.js**, **SomeComponent.svelte** into multiple places.

```
/// index.svelte, blog.svelte

<script>
    import { someConfig1 } from "../Config.js";
    import Url from "../Url.js";
    import SomeComponent from "../SomeComponent.svelte";
</script>


.... some usage
```

So, from what I have noticed in the browser's network tab is that they request to those three resources separately which increase network roundtrip and cause some performance issue especially when having a couple of components or classes. So, my question is it possible to reduce thoese network request count by bundle them together instead of a separate request?

Comment: This should not be that much of a problem with HTTP/2, the preview probably runs on HTTP/1.1, at least it does for me.

Comment: Seem like in my case each network request of 1 KB took between 74ms to 200ms on HTTP/2 on CDN. I am not sure much about HTTP/1.1 though, but 74ms to 200ms is quite high because I have a couple of these kinds of classes plus other resources such as image and icon.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way, the bundler is most probably already doing the optimal possible cutting given what you give it and what's technically safe.

The bundler's main goal is to stuff as much code as it can in the same file for any given entry point. In Kit, an entry point is a page -- that is, a point where you might arrive and want to download only the code that is useful for this page. I trust Kit (and underlying Vite, and underlying Rollup for prod build) for succeeding in that.

But now, if some code is shared between multiple entry points / pages, and you do say that you do "just import Url.js, Config.js, SomeComponent.svelte into multiple places", then the bundler *has* to create another file for this shared code to be, well, shared by those entry points. For safety.

In your example that's just `const` and `static` members of a class, so we see that it could be inlined without a need to be shared. But still, you're exporting a class in one of your module: it can't be *automatically* safe for the bundler to put that same class in the main file for multiple entry points.

`page-1-chunk.js`

```js
class Url { ... }
...
```

`page-2-chunk.js`

```js
class Url { ... }
...
// Oops, myUrl was a Url from page 1 actually
if (myUrl instanceof Url) ...
```

The bundler main goal is efficiency, but its hard constraint is not breaking the semantics of your code, between bundled and non bundled state. When in doubt, it'll err on the side of safety, because slightly less efficient code is unambiguously better than broken code.

What is safe depends on your specific bundler's code analysis capacities, but I'm pretty sure Rollup won't go into the troubles of seeing if you're only using static members of an exported class. I'm less sure whether it's seeing that a module is only exporting constant values, but I wouldn't hold my breath on that. Bundlers mostly work at import/export level...

Now, why are you getting 3, and not 2, requests? We can expect bundlers to stick together shared deps in as few files as possible, as they do for entry points.

But, likewise, they don't have full knowledge of everything when doing so. When you're using `config.js` and `url.js` together in *every* modules that import them, then the bundler should chunk them together. But if there's at least one module using only one of them, what's the bundler to do? Maybe it should put them together in the same chunk, and let your prod build reap the benefit of one less request for entry points that use both, at the extra cost of shipping some unused code to entry points that need only one of them. But maybe the entry point that uses only one of them is your home page and represents 99% of your real world use cases? How could the bundler know? They only go so far into guessing. Guessing it's a tricky business. Bundlers are mainly expected not to break things...

So yeah, you can't expect automatic perfect cutting of your code by bundlers in every situation, because the right decision is usage specific and is beyond their knowledge. Their offer is only safe + best effort.

Now, *you* do know what they miss. So, knowing how they think, you could nudge them into taking even better decisions.

For example, if you know your static class members will really be invariable for the lifetime of the prod application, you could use a search and replace plugin (e.g. `process.env` in Kit), and then the bundler will easily know it's safe to duplicate those values in multiple chunks.

So, actually, it was not a hard "now way".
It depends on how much you understand your app, and your tooling, and how much much you're willing to invest into helping it achieve the best result (and how much the resulting improvement would be really valuable). But, in any case, beating the defaults for this in Kit/Vite/Rollup is not a config switch.

Comment: It does make a lot of sense from your explanation. Each method has different pros and cons. If Svelte inline the code directly into each component, it might break something while it is expected not to do so. And, if it bundle them together, then it may result in an unused code.